# Remove blank item in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS and I have data.json file:

```
<li ng-repeat="cat in ctrl.getCategories()">
          <input type="checkbox"  name="{{cat}}" ng-model="ctrl.filter[cat]" id='{{$index}}' class='chk-btn styled-checkbox' ng-click="removeAnother();"/>
          <label for='{{$index}}'>{{cat}}</label>
</li>
```

But first item is blank because it has no any categories:

```
{"index":0,"cat1":"","class":"test"},
```

And this is the function:

```
  function getCategories() {
    return (self.boxes || []).
    map(function (box) { return box.cat1; }).
    filter(function (box, idx, arr) { return arr.indexOf(box) === idx; });

  }
```

I need remove blank items in ng-repeat. How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use multiple conditions to check the `cat1` isn't empty.

```
function getCategories() {
    return (self.boxes || []).
    map(function (box) { return box.cat1; }).
    filter(function (box, idx, arr) { return arr.indexOf(box) === idx && box !== ''; });    
}
```

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
  var self = this;
  self.getCategories = getCategories;
  self.boxes = [
  {"index":0,"cat1":"","class":"test"},
  {"index":0,"cat1":"1","class":"test"},
  {"index":0,"cat1":"2","class":"test"},

  ]
  
  function getCategories() {
    return (self.boxes || []).
    map(function (box) { return box.cat1; }).
    filter(function (box, idx, arr) { return arr.indexOf(box) === idx && box !== ''; });

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
<li ng-repeat="cat in ctrl.getCategories()">
          <input type="checkbox"  name="{{cat}}" ng-model="ctrl.filter[cat]" id='{{$index}}' class='chk-btn styled-checkbox' ng-click="removeAnother();"/>
          <label for='{{$index}}'>{{cat}}</label>
</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
function getCategories() {
    return (self.boxes || []).
    filter(function (box) { return box.cat1 !== "" });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options, the one is to use ng-if to hide ng-repeated item if cat is blank:

```html
<li ng-repeat="cat in ctrl.getCategories()">
    <div ng-if="cat">
        <input type="checkbox"  name="{{cat}}" ng-model="ctrl.filter[cat]" id='{{$index}}' class='chk-btn styled-checkbox' ng-click="removeAnother();"/>
        <label for='{{$index}}'>{{cat}}</label>    
    </div>
</li>
```

And the another one is to use the getCategories function to do the filtering:

```js
  function getCategories() {
    return (self.boxes || [])
      .map(function (box) { return box.cat1; }).
      .filter(function (box, idx, arr) { 
        return arr.indexOf(box) === idx && box; 
      });
  }
```